# DS Mid-Square Hashing

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hash

While Implementing Mid-Square technique we were thought using Key Values like - 10,25,994.
But what if I was given a single value as key like 5 which results in 25, How will I consider the mid value in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by -10,25,994 ???

Comment: Pas with zeroes. (And consider using more serious hashing techniques.)